# How to keep receiving messages when the master node goes down? [RabbitMQ]

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, mirroring

I have two machines running RabbitMQ, Master(ip1) and Slave(ip2), and I mirrored them, added policy, synced a queue and exchange, but when I'm sending messages and the master goes down the slave stop responding and my application is not able to send messages anymore.

I have a virtual-host, durable queue and exchange, a policy to promote the slave.

The policy

```
Pattern             ^test
Apply to            all
Definition  
ha-mode:            exactly
ha-params:          5
ha-promote-on-failure:  always
ha-promote-on-shutdown: always
ha-sync-mode:           automatic
queue-master-locator:   random
Priority            0
```

This is the Application that I'm using to publish messages (EDIT: The queue is already set on RabbitMQ UI)

```py
import pika
import time

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('usr', 'pass')

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('ip1',
                                       5672,
                                       'virtual_host',
                                       credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(
    exchange="test_exchange",
    exchange_type="direct",
    passive=False,
    durable=True,
    auto_delete=False)

##channel.queue_declare(queue='test', durable=True, exclusive=False, auto_delete=False)

input('Press ENTER to begin')

for i in range(10000):
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='test',
                      body=('Hello World! '+ str(i)))
    time.sleep(0.001)
print(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
```

I wish that when the master goes down, the slave becomes promoted and receives the messages.

Comment: Have you restart your client when master failure. I think connection will not share between nodes.

Comment: Also you should connect to two nodes in your client code.